# Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) says that invoking [super dealloc] is forbidden...what is the alternative?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I'm starting to use iOS5 and I've enabled ARC for my project.  I have a class where on deallocation I save the state of that object.

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [self save];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

However, under ARC, `[super dealloc]` is not allowed?  I thought that it was considered a bug if you don't invoke the dealloc method on the super class in this situation?

So what is the appropriate way to dealloc objects now?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

ARC in iOS 5 is under NDA. That said, judging from publicly available information at the official site of clang, **you just don't write `[super dealloc]`.** That's generated automatically by the compiler. See the clause [7.1.2](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#misc.special_methods.dealloc) of the specification.

Comment: Thanks...that appears to be the case now.