# C++ member variable in Objective-C++ under ARC

Tags: objective-c++, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to use a C++ member in an Objective-C++ class. Something like this:

```
class CPP;
@interface ObjCPP{

    CPP* cppMember;

}
@end
```

Without ARC, I'm able to manager cppMember with subclassing init and dealloc method. But under ARC I can't do this, because when subclassing dealloc I can't write this:

```
[super dealloc];
```

Any idea for this?

Thanks!

Comment: The C++ is completely irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under ARC, it's fine to (and you must) just leave out the `[super dealloc]` in a `-dealloc` implementation. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536832/automatic-reference-counting-arc-says-that-invoking-super-dealloc-is-forbidde).