# Should I call [super viewDidDisappear:animated]; at the beginning or at the end of viewDidDisappear:

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I am refactoring some Objective-C code someone wrote for iOS more than 3 years ago.
I see the viewDidDisapppear: method was overridden this way:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [pagingView unloadData];

    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

It works fine, however I am wondering, the line:

```
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
```

should be at the end or at the beginning.

I know for viewDidAppear: it is good practice to write:

```
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
```

as the first line.

Also, I know for dealloc (if we not using ARC), we write:

```
[super dealloc];
```

at the end.

So I am a bit confused in the case of viewDidDisapppear:, where it should be.
It makes sense for me to invoke the super class' method at the end, but I am kind of confused, not sure if it is good practice or not.

Please let me know if you know the exact answer.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: As a general rule, on create/activate you call super at the beginning, and on destroy/deactivate you call super at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you want to tear down everything before you call the super view's "`viewDidDisappear`", otherwise stuff might get released (or set to `nil` or whatever) unexpectedly out from under you.

Also, [you do not call `[super dealloc]` in the case of ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536832/automatic-reference-counting-arc-says-that-invoking-super-dealloc-is-forbidd).

Comment: Meh. Reluctant +1.  I'd prefer an answer that says: design your vc so the order doesn't matter... ask yourself what could get released by inherited behavior that's out of your control, and consider those things a design mistake.

Comment: It's an outstandingly excellent point danh.  We recently wrote a whole system with "hidingViewWillHide" sort of thingies (I'm sure you get what I mean): if there is something you DO HAVE TO DO, before the "other programmers stuff", you do it in the "will..." -named routines. Nevertheless, for a beginner, there's something to be said for the "at beginning for create, at end for destroy" **"rule of thumb"**.